# Activating Versions History

Tags: 2010

I am using SharePoint 2010, and i want to activate versions future in order to tracking changes in specific columns only.
I don't want to track all columns i need only specific columns please help me how to do that.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think there isn't a non developer way to see this.
Why don't you use a secondary list to keep track the changes of a column? You could have a list named ColumnVersionList for example, with at least the following fields:

1. ColumnVersionName (name of the column that has changed)
2. ColumnVersionValue (new value of the field)

Then create an Event Receiver on the list you want to track changes on and on ItemAdded or ItemUpdated methods add the logic of the code.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You can try the built-in auditing feature. This is a nice [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/431342/Auditing-A-Built-in-Feature-of-SharePoint) to get you started.

Comment: Thank u Mr Miguel but in this way you can't restore the old version